# Sinch SDK callPhoneNumber get crash in the production app

Tags: ios, iphone, sinch

We are using sinch to make phone calls but getting error: **terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Client is not started'** when we use `production` key & secrets.

We tested successfully in sandbox environment not since production app credentials crash the app.

Apple has rejected our app due to crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, this is because the client has not successfully started.

Either you are trying to place a phone call before receiving `clientDidStart` or you are receiving `clientDidFail:client error:error`, in which case something went wrong and `error` should contain more information on what went wrong.

Comment: Yes its says SINErrorDomainApi error 4000 in clientDidFail

Comment: @SidShah: It should also contain a message, probably something along the lines of "InvalidSignature"

Comment: SINErrorDomainApi error 4000.)" UserInfo=0x787d3ff0 {serverCode=, serverMessage=ApplicationNotFound}  Although sinth app apporove in console.

Answer (score 0):

@frals answer is right.

I am just extending it with the code.

```
class SinchCallViewController: UIViewController {
var sinClient: SINClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       sinClient = Sinch.client(withApplicationKey: "your key", applicationSecret: "Your secret key", environmentHost: "clientapi.sinch.com", userId: "your user id")
        sinClient.delegate = self
        sinClient.setSupportCalling(true)
        sinClient.start()
    }
}

extension SinchCallViewController: SINClientDelegate {
    func clientDidStart(_ client: SINClient!) {
        makeTheCall()
    }

    func clientDidFail(_ client: SINClient!, error: Error!) {
        print("error error-->\(error)")
    }
}
```